# Style a specific row or column of a HTML table using the css class for the table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table in html with a CSS class "style". How should this class be used to style a specific row or column in the table?

The following is the HTML code:

```html
<table class="style">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to style the first row alone. This can be done if we have a class for the first tr tag alone. But how to do the same using the class "style"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below snippet. 
Here's the explanation of the **[:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)**.

```css
.style tbody>:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="style">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But this solution can affect the other elements in the page, if there will be more than one tbody tags are present. He is doing safest thing using class for particular element.

Comment: @Shadow check again, it won't.

Answer (score 0):

Your can use the pseudo class selector called [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) which takes parameter of the number of the position of the element.

### The following is an example

```css
.style {
  border: 1px solid olive;
  width: 100px;
}

.style tr:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

.style tr:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
}

.style tr:nth-child(3) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table class="style">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or you can use another pseudo class selector called [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).

### The following is an example

```css
.style {
  border: 1px solid olive;
  width: 100px;
}

.style tr:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: red;
}

.style tr:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: blue;
}

.style tr:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table class="style">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

and here is another way of using another parameter `even` or `odd` on `nth-child` pseudo class selector.

### Example

```css
.style {
  border: 1px solid olive;
  width: 100px;
}

.style tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: black;
}

.style tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<table class="style">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use CSS :nth-child Selector
Here is [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) for your reference.

Example `.style tr:nth-child(1) { background: red; }`

Comment: But how to use nth-child in the above class "style" ?

Comment: .style is your class and TR is element nth-child(1) is first TR element, for this you have to use CSS format except of inline CSS

Comment: I'm Happy to help you. Please accept the solution and upvote it